# Automatically restrict apps background data using Tasker

Tags: tasker, background-data

I've been using Tasker for a couple weeks after receiving [this recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14121/6834), and I have a few beginner questions. Here is one of them.

I've set up a profile to lock the phone after 10 seconds of darkness (cases where phone is in pocket or turned face down). I would also like to save some power by activating the "restrict background data" option while the phone is not being used. It's under *Settings* -> *Power saving* on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5).

[image]

<sup>(Click to enlarge)</sup>

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea, or do the disadvantages outweigh the benefits?
2. Is there a way to toggle the *Restrict background data* option using a task in Tasker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Restrict background data" seems to restrict apps from accessing the network unless they're in the foreground, i.e. visible on the screen.

On Tasker version 4.5u1m for Android 4+, I don't see anything relevant in the Net action category, which is where I'd expect to find something about network access. The Settings action category is just for showing settings dialogs, so it wouldn't be there.

You could turn that "restrict background data" setting on, and then auto-launch any application that you want to update/sync given a particular parameter (e.g. [launch music app when headset inserted](http://tasker.wikidot.com/headsetlaunch), only changed to something like launch google play when I'm signed into a wireless network). Basically you'd be using tasker to put something in the foreground, not switch the setting.

You can also [limit syncing](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1713521), which is one kind of background data.

Comment: Nice idea for a workaround, thanks. I will try it and see if it's sustainable